# Play videos in ASP.NET without the use of HTML5/Video tag

Tags: asp.net, video

Allright so to support older browsers I need to show some videos on my application without the use of HTML5/ to show them and play them, what would be the best way to achieve this?

I'm using a VB user control to serve the HTML5 video to newer browsers.

My code:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="VideoPlayer.ascx.vb"
  Inherits="Online.VideoPlayer" %>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr visible="false" id="rwError" runat="server">
    <td style="padding-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="<% Resources: Dictionary, FoutOpgetreden %>"
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#3C3C3E" Font-Bold="true" EnableTheming="false" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <video id="player" width="100%" height="auto" title="" controls onclick="this.play();"
        runat="server" />
      <embed id="playerOld" width="100%" height="auto" title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4"
        runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isHtml5Compatible = document.createElement('canvas').getContext != undefined;
  if (!isHtml5Compatible) {
    var oldPlayer = document.getElementById("<%= playerOld.ClientID %>");
    oldPlayer.style.display = "block";
    alert(oldPlayer.style.display);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think in HTML4 it was just `<embed src="SomeVideo.mp4"/>` (with additional attributes available, of course).

Comment: Allright I'll give it a try thanks @David !

Comment: @David how do I go about to get controls in my embed except program them all separately?

Comment: If you're looking for controls outside of whatever component is playing the video itself then you're probably going to be looking for some old-style video player widget.  Which, in pre-HTML5, is probably Flash-based.  HTML didn't have those capabilities natively.

Comment: Allright so I have everything set up right now except it doesn't show the video while display and stuff is set to block, I'll update the OP with some code @David